# Eclipse Programs to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way I can call .java files from eclipse to programs in android studio and have that code be run from android studio? I cannot have the code directly copied into android studio as it brings up multiple issues. So I am wondering if there is some way I can call the .java from Eclipse, get the result from the method within that Eclipse program, and pass that result to android studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Comment: You'll likely get a more reasonable response if you include the issues you have porting your code to Android Studio

Comment: @ManikandanK that's not exactly what I am trying to do. I do not want to import eclipse files in at all. I just want to know if there is some way I can run the code in eclipse, get the result, and pass it to android studio?

Comment: @cricket_007 we meet again! But the issue was that, when everyone was running the code for the Spotify I posted yesterday, it was working in eclipse, but when I literally copy and paste that exact same code into android studio, I am getting network issues when I run it. Therefore I am looking for a different solution to this.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The IDE isn't what is running the code. The Android Device is.

Comment: @cricket_007 alright thank you

Comment: I will take a look at your other question. I was going to the other day, but my IDE got uninstalled for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, no you can't "just call" code from another IDE.

You *could* export the Eclipse code to a JAR, import as a library into Android Studio, then try to work around that, but that sounds like a lot of work.

---

In regards to [your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778892/can-i-execute-this-code-through-an-android-app-without-any-apis), plus your comment.

> it was working in eclipse, but when I literally copy and paste that exact same code into android studio, I am getting network issues when I run it.

**[Android has a UI Thread](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)** that does not like to handle Network requests like your bare single-threaded Eclipse project.

You need a separate thread. Without any libraries, there is AsyncTask, and [**the Android documentation covers this**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Though, you may find OkHttp to be better documented, useful, and less confusing than AsyncTasks. Volley is another, though works fine, is not very well documented.

See more discussion at [Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)

Answer (score 0):

No, This is not possible way to do. Android studio and eclipse are different Applications and you cannot pass the Result to each other.
You can import the project or copy the files for a new Project.